# Как разбить текст на слова?

Tags: html, javascript

Я с помощью функции `split(" ")` создаю массив слов из textarea, но слова, которые были написаны с новой строчки через "Enter", не попадают в массив. Скажите, пожалуйста, как это исправить.  
Можно обойтись без регулярных выражений?

Comment: Функция split принимает не только строку, но и regexp

Comment: Может, это `split("\n")` заработает?

Comment: split("\n") не заработает. Потому что останутся слова, которые пишутся через пробел.

Comment: Я имел ввиду `"\n"` можно для начала сделать реплейс всех `\n` на пробел, а потом сплит пробел :)

Comment: Работает, но только для первого встретившийся элемента:
  
    var text = $("#id_Domains").val().replace("\n"," ").split(" ");

а потом опять

    ["asdasd", "asd", "as↵d↵as↵da↵sd↵as↵d"]

Comment: Оло-ло, что вы тут городите, задача решается `value.split(/\s/)`.

«Найдет любой пробельный символ, включая пробел, табуляцию, переводы строки и другие юникодные пробельные символы.» http://javascript.ru/basic/regular-expression+

value.split(/[ \n]/) — если нужно только `_` и `\n`

Comment: Можно и так =)) 
Спасибо. Но регулярные выражения это не есть хорошо. И я хотел без них. Но видимо так не получается.

Comment: «Не есть хорошо» — откройте тайну почему? А то мужики то не знают.

Comment: @RubaXa, я отталкивался от оп-поста `"Можно обойтись без регулярных выражений?"`

Comment: Ну я вот не в состоянии понять, зачем такое условие, оно у меня даже из поля зрения выпало по причине своей абсурдности :]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проще некуда на самом деле...

```
var result = text.split( "\n" ).join( " " ).split( " " );
```

```js
var text = $("#text").val();
var result = text.split( "\n" ).join( " " ).split( " " );
var strResult = JSON.stringify( result );
$("#result").html( strResult );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="text">слово1 слово2 слово3
  слово4 слово5
  слово6</textarea>
<BR/>
<PRE id="result"></PRE>
```

Comment: а если большой текст и есть точка в конце каждого предложения? есть еще и другие знаки препинания?